# PHP | Parse specific german date format to yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: php, date

Hey I am struggling with a date format . I need to adjust the display of some dates in a wordpress project.

**Its not a duplicate of [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31583577/php-parse-date-from-localized-format) I tried the suggestion over there and its not working with that specific date format.**

What I have is `german date` in the format `D, d. MM yyyy` looking like this: `Fr, 6. Mai 2022`

I want to convert it to `yyyy-mm-dd` = `2022-05-06` but I cant get it work. I have tried to use [date_parse_from_format](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.date-parse-from-format.php) and [date_create_from_format](https://www.php.net/manual/de/datetime.createfromformat.php) but it seems to fail because of the german month and day names.

```
$date_german = 'Fr, 6. Mai 2022';
$date_english = 'Fri, 6. May 2022';
print_r(date_create_from_format('D, d. F Y', $date_german)); // doesn't work
print_r(date_create_from_format('D, d. F Y', $date_english)); // works ()
```

Another try with IntlDateFormatter

```
$date = 'Fr, 6. Mai 2022';
$formatter = new IntlDateFormatter("de_DE", IntlDateFormatter::SHORT, IntlDateFormatter::NONE);
$formatter->setPattern('D, d. F Y');
$unixtime=$formatter->parse($date);
$datetime=new DateTime();
$datetime->setTimestamp($unixtime);
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d');
```

Not working either, it returns: `1970-01-01` because $unixtime is empty?

I also tried to setLocale to de_DE before formatting, but still same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IMO correct way to do this is indeed to use `IntlDateFormatter` however you're using the wrong format constants.

This should work:

```
$date = 'Fr, 6. Mai 2022';
$formatter = new IntlDateFormatter("de_DE", IntlDateFormatter::SHORT, IntlDateFormatter::NONE);
$formatter->setPattern('EEEEEE, d. MMM y');
$unixtime=$formatter->parse($date);
$datetime=new DateTime();
$datetime->setTimestamp($unixtime);
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d');
```

The list of constants for intl is at https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/format_parse/datetime/

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately your code returns `2021-12-31`

Comment: Possibly a known bug: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=77733

Comment: It works now after I changed the pattern to 'EEE, d. MMM yyyy'

Comment: @xDrago it also works with `EEEEEE, d. MMM y` I made a mistake with the year constant  and used the "week year" rather than the actual year