# Convert german date string into date and check if its before today

Tags: php, date, datetime, strtotime

I have a string with my german date `Freitag - 09. September 2022 - 14:00` (Format is: `l - d. F Y - H:i`). It need to be displayed in this format on my homepage thats why its in this format.

Now i want to parse this string into a date that i can check if the given date is before todays date (i only want to check day, month and year, so time is unnecessary).

I already tried a lot of things with `strtotime` and also `DateTime::createFromFormat` but nothing worked for me.

Is there any solution for that?

Comment: I understand you use php date and format it for creating this string. Can you check the given date with this date (before it is formatting like string) instead that retrieve the date from string?

Comment: Can you try with the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/72147814/1213708

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the IntlDateFormatter to parse the German date. This requires the intl PHP extension.

```
$germanDateText  = 'Freitag - 09. September 2022 - 14:00';
$formatter       = new IntlDateFormatter('de-DE', IntlDateFormatter::FULL, IntlDateFormatter::FULL, 'Europe/Berlin', IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN, 'EEEE - dd. MMMM yyyy - HH:mm');
$germanTimestamp = $formatter->parse($germanDateText);
$germanDayStart  = strtotime(date('Y-m-d', $germanTimestamp));
$todayDayStart   = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));

$isBeforeToday   = $germanDayStart < $todayDayStart;
var_dump($isBeforeToday);
```

#### Output

```
bool(true)
```

Comment: Works great! Just one thing: its 2 hours late since its currently summertime in germany. So 6 October - 1:59 would say its 5 October. Can i somehow easily check this? Also with wintertime which is 1 hour late? Thanks!

Comment: You could use a timezone. `$timezone = new DateTimeZone('UTC');
$formatter = new IntlDateFormatter('de-DE', IntlDateFormatter::FULL, IntlDateFormatter::FULL, $timezone, IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN, 'EEEE - dd. MMMM yyyy - HH:mm');`